# VS2008: Define the same code analysis settings for a whole solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-analysis, fxcop

I want to use the built in code analysis feature in Visual Studio 2008.

The settings seems to be only set on a project level. How can I set code analysis settings globally for the entire solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move your code analysis settings into a separate file referenced in your project files.  For details, see http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2006/11/16/faq-how-do-i-share-managed-code-analysis-rule-settings-over-multiple-projects-david-kean.aspx.  Personally, I generally use separate configurations (via separate files) for "real" projects and test projects, but ymmv...

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but this seems to be the only thing that is supported :-)